# Too many hauling routes

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Playing a succession game with my brother. After 10 Dorfyears or so, the amount of hauling routes has become a bit unmanageable.
Does anyone know of a convenient way to locate the routes / stops, so I can toggle through them, just to remind myself where they are again?
Thanks.

Comment: To illustrate how cumbersome this really is:  
I `View Rooms/Buildings`, then (using DFHack) press `s` to  search for `track stop`. This gives me an undescriptive list of Track Stop buildings (no kidding). I then select the 1st, `Enter` to view building info brings up a black screen. The map on the right does not help either. Then I press `t` to zoom to the building items. Next I always have trouble locating the cursor. I put the cursor next to the track stop, then open the hauling routes screen `h`, toggle through  the stops to see if this Track Stop lights up.  
Then the 2nd Track Stop, etc.

Comment: I don't have a solution for your specific question but have a recommendation that may help in the future. Learn how to use the notes feature in DF and then use detailed notes on every feature of note when you (or your brother) place them, so that you can see what that track-stop or lever is for, and possibly why you built it that way. This not only helps in succession games but also when you re-embark since you won't have to remember what that unknown lever you built 6 months ago does. Or you could just go "Let's pull it and find out" and have !!FUN!! finding out the hard way.